# Issue with list indexing while converting letters (devnagari to english)

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-unicode

I am currently trying to map devnagari script with English alphabets. But once in a while I run into the error **list index out of range** . I don't want to miss out on any list . This is why I do not want to use error handling unless it is necessary. Could you please look into my script and help out why this error is occurring ? 
In my word file I have located which word is causing the error but then If i use couple of sentence up and down from that word then the error is not there . i.e I think the error happens at a specific length of string.

```
   clean=[]
dafuq=[]
clean_list = []
replacements = {'अ':'A','आ':'AA', 'इ':'I', 'ई':'II', 'उ':'U','ऊ':'UU', 'ए':'E', 'ऐ':'AI',
                'ओ':'O','औ':'OU', 'क':'KA', 'ख':'KHA', 'ग':'GA', 'घ':'GHA', 'ङ':'NGA',
                'च':'CA','छ':'CHHA', 'ज':'JA', 'झ':'JHA','ञ':'NIA', 'ट':'TA', 'ठ':'THA',
                'ड':'DHA','ढ':'DHHA', 'ण':'NAE', 'त':'TA', 'थ':'THA','द':'DA', 'ध':'DHA',
                'न':'NA','प':'PA', 'फ':'FA', 'ब':'B', 'भ':'BHA', 'म':'MA','य':'YA', 'र':'RA',
                'ल':'L','व':'WA', 'स':'SA', 'ष':'SHHA', 'श':'SHA', 'ह':'HA', '्':'A',
                'ऋ':'RI', 'ॠ':'RI','ऌ':'LI','ॐ':'OMS', 'ः':' ', 'ँ':'U',
                'ं':'M', 'ृ':'RI', 'ा':'AA', 'ी':'II', 'ि':'I', 'े':'E', 'ै':'AI',
                'ो':'O','ौ':'OU','ु' :'U','ू':'UU'  }

import unicodedata
from functools import reduce

def reducer(r, v):
    if unicodedata.category(v) in ('Mc', 'Mn'):
        r[-1] = r[-1] + v
    else:
        r.append(v)
    return r

with open('words_original.txt', mode='r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
  with open ('alphabeths.txt', mode='w+', encoding='utf-8') as d:
     with open('only_words.txt', mode='w+', encoding="utf-8") as e:



          chunk_size = 4096
          f_chunk = f.read(chunk_size)

          while len(f_chunk)>0:

              for word in f_chunk.split():


                 for char in ['।', ',', '’', '‘', '?','#','1','2','3','4','0','5','6','7','8','9',
                              '१','२','३','४','५','.''६','७','८','९','०', '5','6','7','8','9','0','\ufeff']:
                     if char in word:
                        word = word.replace(char, '')

                 if word.strip():
                  clean_list.append(word)

              f_chunk = f.read(chunk_size)

              for clean_word in clean_list:


               test_word= reduce(reducer,clean_word,[])

               final_word=  (''.join(test_word))
               dafuq.append(final_word)
               print (final_word)
  f_chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
```

This is the file I am testing it on

words_original.txt

[words_original.txt](http://pastebin.com/hGERkbRm)

stacktrace error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KUSHAL\Desktop\EARTHQUAKE_PYTHON\test.py", line 82, in <module>
    test_word= reduce(reducer,clean_word,[])
  File "C:\Users\KUSHAL\Desktop\EARTHQUAKE_PYTHON\test.py", line 27, in reducer
    r[-1] = r[-1] + v
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Remove all the unnecessary comments from code, run the code, and provide us with the full stack trace so that we can help.

Comment: @thefourtheye sure. done!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay with some unicode characters. It worked after removing them.